# Installing JDK on Windows 10 - MsiEnumProducts error 1610 due to broken WBEM library/WMI library

Tags: windows, java, wmi, wmic

I failing on installing JDK 8 on an x64 Windows 10 installation or updating from any older version to the up-to-date version.

After the usual Java Update failed with no error message whatsoever,

- I decided to do a clean reinstall, and deleted all old versions with Your Uninstaller, and also manually removed the directories that were left and also the `JAVA_HOME` variable.
- I then downloaded the JDK installer. On running the installer, I don't get any error message, it just fails quietly.
- I tried safe mode, admin rights and/or without antivirus software, to no avail.
- took a look at the event log. It's in German, which is why I won't copy/paste that now, but it basically says that `jdk-8u65-windows-x64.exe` failed with error `0x40000015` which is just the "unknown software exception".
- then i looked into %TEMP%. There, on each instance of `jdk-8u65-windows-

  x64.exe`, a log is maintained in `jusched.log`. I always got the error     `MsiEnumProducts(75) failed with error=[1610]`.
- then i looked at any leftovers from old installations in my Windows;
  I ran an AutoFix from my old Your Installer version that checks for
  that, and also a CCleaner session, but no significant errors were
  found.
- I also checked whether there's any good possibility of manually
  installing JDK 8 x64, but didn't find any really helpful links. Then
  I tried to unzip the installer with 7-zip. I unpacked the folder tree
  into `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\`, and set `JAVA_HOME` again,
  but when I tried to point IntelliJ IDEA to that directory as my JDK,
  it kept telling me that it's "not a valid JDK directory" (also
  neither of the subdirectories), although the Java files are present
  in the `\bin`. So next I went to reinstalling JDK 6 (worked), then
  updating to 7 (worked); but still, update to JDK 8 failed as before.

  Then I tried installing JRE instead of JDK as a tryout, but JRE 8 fails the same way as JDK 8 does, without any visible errors. The error log in `jusched.log` now differs to before any JDK was installed.
  Here's what it says now on a JDK 8 installation attempt (I'll crop out all the config stuff that seemingly produced no errors):

> [2015/10/22 18:29:09.178, jdk-8u65-windows-x64.exe (PID: 6068, TID:
>   1808), MsiUtils.cpp:308 (msi::`anonymous-namespace'::makeMessage)]
>         ERROR: Exception with message 'Resources.cpp(66) at Resource::getPtr(): cannot find resource (name='#259', type='#6').
>   System error [1814](system error 1814 (Der angegebene Ressourcenname
>   wurde nicht in der Image-Datei gefunden))' caught
>       [2015/10/22 18:29:09.179, jdk-8u65-windows-x64.exe (PID: 6068, TID: 1808), JavaEnvironment.cpp:89
>   (`anonymous-namespace'::getMsiProperty)]
>         ERROR: Exception with message 'MsiUtils.cpp(268) at msi::Database::getProperty():
>   MsiViewFetch(C:\WINDOWS\Installer\1c487c.msi, SELECT Value FROM
>   Property WHERE Property = 'FullVersion') failed. MSI error [259]'
>   caught
>       [2015/10/22 18:29:09.179, jdk-8u65-windows-x64.exe (PID: 6068, TID: 1808), JavaEnvironment.cpp:451
>   (`anonymous-namespace'::getInstalledJava)]
>         TRACE: InstalledJava(1.6.0_45|1.6.0_45|JDK|64bit|C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45|{64A3A4F4-B792-11D6-A78A-00B0D0160450}|-10)
>       [2015/10/22 18:29:09.180, jdk-8u65-windows-x64.exe (PID: 6068, TID: 1808), JavaEnvironment.cpp:489 (JavaEnvironment::detect)]
>         TRACE: Installed Java detected: version=1.7.0; arch=64; productCode={64A3A4F4-B792-11D6-A78A-00B0D0170800}; type=1
>       [2015/10/22 18:29:09.180, jdk-8u65-windows-x64.exe (PID: 6068, TID: 1808), JavaEnvironment.cpp:139
>   (`anonymous-namespace'::detectHomeDir)]
>         TRACE: Find home dir of {64A3A4F4-B792-11D6-A78A-00B0D0170800} Java installation
>       [2015/10/22 18:29:09.180, jdk-8u65-windows-x64.exe (PID: 6068, TID: 1808), JavaEnvironment.cpp:303
>   (`anonymous-namespace'::detectFullVersion)]
>         TRACE: Detect full version of {64A3A4F4-B792-11D6-A78A-00B0D0170800} Java installation
>       [2015/10/22 18:29:09.181, jdk-8u65-windows-x64.exe (PID: 6068, TID: 1808), JavaEnvironment.cpp:214
>   (`anonymous-namespace'::detectFullVersionFromMsi)]
>         TRACE: detectFullVersionFromMsi({64A3A4F4-B792-11D6-A78A-00B0D0170800})
>       [2015/10/22 18:29:09.187, jdk-8u65-windows-x64.exe (PID: 6068, TID: 1808), MsiUtils.cpp:308
>   (msi::`anonymous-namespace'::makeMessage)]
>         ERROR: Exception with message 'Resources.cpp(66) at Resource::getPtr(): cannot find resource (name='#259', type='#6').
>   System error [1814](system error 1814 (Der angegebene Ressourcenname
>   wurde nicht in der Image-Datei gefunden))' caught
>       [2015/10/22 18:29:09.187, jdk-8u65-windows-x64.exe (PID: 6068, TID: 1808), JavaEnvironment.cpp:89
>   (`anonymous-namespace'::getMsiProperty)]
>         ERROR: Exception with message 'MsiUtils.cpp(268) at msi::Database::getProperty():
>   MsiViewFetch(C:\WINDOWS\Installer\1c4882.msi, SELECT Value FROM
>   Property WHERE Property = 'FullVersion') failed. MSI error [259]'
>   caught
>       [2015/10/22 18:29:09.188, jdk-8u65-windows-x64.exe (PID: 6068, TID: 1808), JavaEnvironment.cpp:451
>   (`anonymous-namespace'::getInstalledJava)]
>         TRACE: InstalledJava(1.7.0_80|1.7.0_80|JDK|64bit|C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80|{64A3A4F4-B792-11D6-A78A-00B0D0170800}|-10)

and on a JRE 8 installation attempt:

```
[2015/10/22 18:31:56.888, jre-8u65-windows-au.exe (PID: 9704, TID: 6008), JavaEnvironment.cpp:472 (JavaEnvironment::detect)]
    TRACE: Entering JavaEnvironment::detect
[2015/10/22 18:31:56.929, jre-8u65-windows-au.exe (PID: 9704, TID: 6008), JavaEnvironment.cpp:489 (JavaEnvironment::detect)]
    TRACE: Installed Java detected: version=1.7.0_80; arch=64; productCode={26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F06417080FF}; type=0
[2015/10/22 18:31:56.931, jre-8u65-windows-au.exe (PID: 9704, TID: 6008), JavaEnvironment.cpp:139 (`anonymous-namespace'::detectHomeDir)]
    TRACE: Find home dir of {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F06417080FF} Java installation
[2015/10/22 18:31:56.940, jre-8u65-windows-au.exe (PID: 9704, TID: 6008), JavaEnvironment.cpp:303 (`anonymous-namespace'::detectFullVersion)]
    TRACE: Detect full version of {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F06417080FF} Java installation
[2015/10/22 18:31:56.940, jre-8u65-windows-au.exe (PID: 9704, TID: 6008), JavaEnvironment.cpp:214 (`anonymous-namespace'::detectFullVersionFromMsi)]
    TRACE: detectFullVersionFromMsi({26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F06417080FF})
[2015/10/22 18:31:56.948, jre-8u65-windows-au.exe (PID: 9704, TID: 6008), JavaEnvironment.cpp:327 (`anonymous-namespace'::detectJreMode)]
    TRACE: Detect mode of {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F06417080FF} Java installation
[2015/10/22 18:31:56.949, jre-8u65-windows-au.exe (PID: 9704, TID: 6008), JavaEnvironment.cpp:451 (`anonymous-namespace'::getInstalledJava)]
    TRACE: InstalledJava(1.7.0_80-b15|1.7.0_80-b15|JRE|64bit|C:\Program Files\Java\jre7|{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F06417080FF}|10)
[2015/10/22 18:31:56.950, jre-8u65-windows-au.exe (PID: 9704, TID: 6008), JavaEnvironment.cpp:489 (JavaEnvironment::detect)]
    TRACE: Installed Java detected: version=1.6.0_45; arch=64; productCode={26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86416045FF}; type=0
[2015/10/22 18:31:56.951, jre-8u65-windows-au.exe (PID: 9704, TID: 6008), JavaEnvironment.cpp:139 (`anonymous-namespace'::detectHomeDir)]
    TRACE: Find home dir of {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86416045FF} Java installation
[2015/10/22 18:31:56.956, jre-8u65-windows-au.exe (PID: 9704, TID: 6008), JavaEnvironment.cpp:303 (`anonymous-namespace'::detectFullVersion)]
    TRACE: Detect full version of {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86416045FF} Java installation
[2015/10/22 18:31:56.956, jre-8u65-windows-au.exe (PID: 9704, TID: 6008), JavaEnvironment.cpp:214 (`anonymous-namespace'::detectFullVersionFromMsi)]
    TRACE: detectFullVersionFromMsi({26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86416045FF})
[2015/10/22 18:31:56.963, jre-8u65-windows-au.exe (PID: 9704, TID: 6008), JavaEnvironment.cpp:327 (`anonymous-namespace'::detectJreMode)]
    TRACE: Detect mode of {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86416045FF} Java installation
[2015/10/22 18:31:56.964, jre-8u65-windows-au.exe (PID: 9704, TID: 6008), JavaEnvironment.cpp:451 (`anonymous-namespace'::getInstalledJava)]
    TRACE: InstalledJava(1.6.0_45-b06|1.6.0_45-b06|JRE|64bit|C:\Program Files\Java\jre6|{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86416045FF}|10)
[2015/10/22 18:31:56.964, jre-8u65-windows-au.exe (PID: 9704, TID: 6008), JavaEnvironment.cpp:489 (JavaEnvironment::detect)]
    TRACE: Installed Java detected: version=1.6.0; arch=64; productCode={64A3A4F4-B792-11D6-A78A-00B0D0160450}; type=1
[2015/10/22 18:31:56.965, jre-8u65-windows-au.exe (PID: 9704, TID: 6008), JavaEnvironment.cpp:489 (JavaEnvironment::detect)]
    TRACE: Installed Java detected: version=1.7.0; arch=64; productCode={64A3A4F4-B792-11D6-A78A-00B0D0170800}; type=1
[2015/10/22 18:31:56.968, jre-8u65-windows-au.exe (PID: 9704, TID: 6008), JavaEnvironment.cpp:0 (JavaEnvironment::detect)]
    TRACE: Exiting JavaEnvironment::detect (entered at JavaEnvironment.cpp:472)
[2015/10/22 18:31:56.969, jre-8u65-windows-au.exe (PID: 9704, TID: 6008), jinstall.cpp:1392 (WinMain)]
    ERROR: Exception with message 'KnownProductCodeInstalledJavaTracker.cpp(205) at KnownProductCodeInstalledJavaTracker::next(): MsiEnumProducts(78) failed with error=[1610]' caught
```

So, in summary, the installation fails because the MsiEnumProducts seemingly lists some installation, presumably some old Java installation, that isn't found, or the installer isn't found. But how can I find out what's missing? Or which registry entry is redundant? I looked for registry entries mentioning JDK or `C:\Program Files\Java` and found some that seemed redundant, and deleted them, but that, too, didn't change anything.

On the web and on SE, I found many questions that pointed to the same problem, but rarely did any address the (probable) core of the problem, the MsiEnumProducts failure. Specifically [these](https://superuser.com/questions/128254/cannot-install-jdk) [two](https://superuser.com/questions/422823/jdk-installer-doesnt-install) on this site.

Any hints on this tricky situation?

If I didn't know any better, I'd say that the hint to the origin of the error is:

```
[2015/10/22 18:29:09.181, jdk-8u65-windows-x64.exe (PID: 6068, TID: 1808), JavaEnvironment.cpp:214 (`anonymous-namespace'::detectFullVersionFromMsi)]
    TRACE: detectFullVersionFromMsi({64A3A4F4-B792-11D6-A78A-00B0D0170800})
[2015/10/22 18:29:09.187, jdk-8u65-windows-x64.exe (PID: 6068, TID: 1808), MsiUtils.cpp:308 (msi::`anonymous-namespace'::makeMessage)]
    ERROR: Exception with message 'Resources.cpp(66) at Resource::getPtr(): cannot find resource (name='#259', type='#6'). System error [1814](system error 1814 (Der angegebene Ressourcenname wurde nicht in der Image-Datei gefunden))' caught
```

So, basically, my question is before all others, how do I find out, what resource is #259 type #6 and where is it registered?

Comment: I have the same problem with Windows 7, 8u60 and 8u65. 8u51 is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a proper solution to the problem in adequate time and the need to have Java 8 running on the device became too urgent, so I had to to a clean reinstall of Windows 10 after all, and after that, everything worked. Before that, I dug a little deeper:

- I found that in Windows PowerShell, `wmic product` didn't work at all and always quit with a "general error", which was logged in the Eventlog as "generic error" (I forgot the exact error #, but it was unspecific).
- I also tried rebuilding the `wbem` subdirectory in `system32`, which is basically the WMI repository for Windows, with the help [of this tutorial](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2009/04/13/wmi-rebuilding-the-wmi-repository.aspx), but this also didn't resolve the problem

So in conclusion, I can say that this type of failure during JDK installation is a symptom of a broken WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) installer library, and the method MsiEnumProducts, which is used by JDK, therefore fails with a general error. The error can be reproduced without JDK installation when you check the status of your WMI product library by entering `wmic product` in Windows Powershell. Therefore, the error is probably not specific to JDK installation, but the usage of this enumeration may be so rare that the error generally only rarely does have an impact on the system and is therefore reported only rarely. Maybe for the same reason, a real solution, in my opinion, to this date does not exist, so all I can say is if you encounter this error on your system, save your time and do a clean reinstall of Windows, it will cost you less time than further evaluating this.

As for the origins of this problem, IMHO it is very hard to tell. I do consider myself a power user, manipulating the registry from time to time, running cleaners when I think they're needed, and so on, but this would be the first time in 20 years of Windows that I really broke the registry, and I couldn't even say when or with what.
Another option, in my opinion, is that I upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 8.1, not having a clean reinstall, and I had been using Windows 8.1 for quite a while before. I also encountered [that bug where the WiFi is broken if a VPN client is present during Windows 10 upgrade](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3084164), and I wouldn't be surprised if the upgrade left other collateral damages as well due to some deeply buried incompatibility or inconsistency.

[tl;dr] If you encounter the above mentioned error, do a clean reinstall of Windows 10 if you really need to use JDK 8 or want to avoid possible further problems with other installers in the future, and if you do not believe there will be a miraculous hotfix by Microsoft in the near future regarding a broken WMI installer library.

Answer (score 2):

I've faced the same trouble and found that my list of products (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Installer\Products`) was broken. Always check it as well as `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products`. Having some bad IDs (like the one with underscore in it) may lead Micorosoft Installer to report `ERROR_BAD_CONFIGURATION` (1610).

Comment: yeah, when I later dug a little deeper I found the same (see my own answer to this). But I couldn't fix it, could you? After weighing the alternatives, I found that a clean reinstall would actually save time here.

Comment: @cirko make sure you have only GUIDs there, no junk line underscores. Try to delete entry (backup first!) and check again. To make sure your installer serivce works, do ``wmic product``.

Comment: This helped in my case. The problem was BootCamp services.